# Indefinite Articles for Proper Nouns

Tags: articles

Is the article "a" OK in this sentence?

"The door opened, revealing *a* laughing John."

Thank you very much!

Comment: Oh, thank you! 

Comment: Also related: [Is it {ever} correct to have 'a' before a proper noun?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/200434/is-it-correct-to-have-a-before-a-proper-noun) // 'He returned to a badly battered London' is perhaps a more obvious example of the change of state @StuartF mentions. (If you can find a supporting reference, Stuart, an answer would be valuable.)

Comment: Yes, but bear in mind it would work the same way in French in this case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [indefinite article before proper names.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/87942/indefinite-article-before-proper-names) Also [Indefinite article with the names of people](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/139333/) and [Indefinite/definite article before an adjective + a person's name ("**an exasperated Einstein**")](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/102793/), among others.

Answer (score 0):

The is an "a" before laughing is because it's a description of John at this moment. We're seeing a temporary concept when we open the door and using the indefinite article make that clearer.

"The door opened, revealing John laughing at Jane's joke." Here John is a specific person who just happens to be doing something.

Now if John's nickname was "Laughing John" then "The door opened, revealing Laughing John" is correct.